# Unable to create login to SQL server using create method of SMO

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a new login to SQL server 2005 using SMO . The trouble is the create method keeps on failing with the error : Exception calling create with 1 argument . Can someone please point me out where i am going wrong and what is the way out .

```
$server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server localhost
$login = New-Object  -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login
                     -ArgumentList $server, $loginName
$login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin
$login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
$login.Create($password)
```

Comment: where are you passing the `$login.Create($loginName)` ?

Comment: $login = New-Object  -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login
                     -ArgumentList $server, $loginName

Comment: Loginname i am pasing when i am directly creating the login object